# Inserir link na imagem de popup do FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

Como inserir um link na imagem que é aberta (popup) no fancybox após o clique?

Trecho do código HTML:

```
<li> 
  <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="imagem_grande.jpg" title="nome_produto">
    <img src="imagem_pequena.jpg" alt="Imagem Pequena." />
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Você tem algum trecho de código? Se sim poste, pois facilitaria na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Não foi bem o que eu queria, mas consegui inserir o link dentro do "title", vejam:

```
title="<a href="www.exemplo.com" target="_blank">Nome do Produto</a>"
```

Só não gostei porque quando passa o mouse sobre a imagem, retorna todo o conteúdo do title, que não ficou muito agradável.

Comment: Aguardo sugestões.

Comment: use o atributo `content` em vez de `title`. http://fancybox.net/api